# Display two camera preview in same activity

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

Is it possible to display two camera previews in same activity? We have two camera previews. One is placed top half of the activity window and other is placed in the bottom half of the activity window. Back camera preview is at the top and front camera preview is at the bottom.

Need to open only one camera at a time.

If it is possible how we can avoid the stretching of a specific sized camera preview? For eg. camera preview with size 200 x 200.

Comment: Perhaps with `TextureView` on API Level 14+. Probably not with `SurfaceView`.

Comment: What kind of stretch do you ask to avoid? Maybe you can post an illustration?

Comment: Hey @lal i had a same Problem. now i am developing a camera App and i also want to use more Camera Preview on a single activity.that is why i need solution of this Question..please tell me if you found any Best way..PLEASE...):

Comment: I didn't get the answer at that time. May be we can do this now by using TextureView.

Comment: ok.bro thanks for answer...(: